# Moq: Can I verify that a setter was only called N times?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I am testing a property that has a public setter but a private getter.
I know that I can verify that a setter was called with a given value twice:

```
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 0, Times.Once());
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 1, Times.Once());
```

but what I can't seem to do is verify that it the setter was called exactly twice.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `Times.Exactly` method:

```
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 0, Times.Exactly(N));
```

**Update** 
I've got your point incorrectly at the first time until you've clarified it in comment.

You can write following asserts in your test:

```
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 0, Times.Once);
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 1, Times.Once);
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = It.IsNotIn(0, 1), Times.Never);
```

It is exactly testing your desired behaviour: test will pass only if `CurrentIndex` wat set exactly two times: once to 0, another time to 1 and no other values/times are permitted.

Comment: No, that's not quite what I want. I want to check that it was called once with '0' , once with '1' and on no other occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understanded correctly. If you don't need to know the value used in CurrentIndex than you can use this:

```
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = It.IsAny<Int32>(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

But if you do need to verify the value in CurrentIndex you'll need to do the way you are already doing, or a `for` if the number of times is too high.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 0, Times.Once());
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = 1, Times.Once());
mockTable.VerifySet(m => m.CurrentIndex = It.IsAny<int>(), Times.Exactly(2));
```